# Linking node at the same depth in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

You are given a class Node

```
public class Node {
    Node left;
    Node right;
    Node next;
}
```

Now given a node which is the root of a binary tree (which is not a complete binary tree, some node only has left or right child), you need to set the `next` field for all `Node`s in the tree so that all `Node`s at the same depth are connected in a linked list from left to right.

And you are not supposed to use linear amount of addition memory such as annotating each node with its depth. This means no extra field like `int depth` in the class `Node` or similar intent such as a map `Map<Node, Integer>`.

I can easily solve this if I can set the node depth and do a BFS traversing on the tree. I set `next` for the previous node when I have current node and previous node at the same depth.

However, the interviewer asked me NOT to annotate depth of each node.
Please help me solve this. Thanks. And please tell me if the running time is still `O(n)` for the non-annotating solution.

Comment: Is the reason you cannot anotate nodes or is to push for sublinear space solution? It can be done without anotating by holding two queues in the BFS, one for current depth and one for next depth, and switch between them when one is exhausted - but that remains O(n) space, with O(n) time.

Comment: Another option with O(h) space and O(n^2) time is [IDDFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search)

Comment: @amit `O(n^2)` is terrible solution while we can have `O(n)` with just linear amount of memory to annotate the depth. Do you know of better solution?

Comment: Yes, I showed a solution with linear time and linear space in the first comment (and now answer as well)/

Comment: @amit Please let me correct myself, I meant to say that we can easily annotate the depth with linear amount of memory. So can we have a solution that uses sub linear memory and still linear running time (or even `O(nlogn)` time with sub linear memory is fine. `O(n^2)` time is bad.

Comment: So the question is not about how to do it without annotating, it is how to do it in sublinear space. that's a different question, please edit.

Comment: @amit Edited. I just want to confirm that the question is not a very good one. I felt pretty bad that I could not solve it in the interview.

Comment: It could be he did look for the two-fronts solution, because it shows you understand how BFS works, and that you understand two fronts are going to be enough for it.

Comment: @amit The question is a good one. There is a good answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you know the tree's height `h` (could be calculated in `O(n)` time and log space). By maintaining the tail's for all `h` lists, you can use DFS to generate the lists. You will only need to store `h` tail elements and the call stack parameters (`O(log n)` additional space):

Initialize:

```
listTails := array with h null entries (type Node)
n := root
depth := 0
```

And call:

```
function buildLists(Node n, int depth, Node[] listTails)
{
    if(n == null)
        return;

    if(listTails[depth] != null)
        listTails[depth].next = n;
    listTails[depth] = n;

    buildLists(n.left, depth + 1, listTails);
    buildLists(n.right, depth + 1, listTails);
}
```

If you use a dynamic-size data store for the list tails (e.g. a `std::vector<>` in C++), it is not even necessary to know `h` beforehand.

This essentially propagates a front from left to right through the entire tree.

Comment: This is what I think is what he looks for. Good one.